# find + sed append line to beginning of file only if not there

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I am writing a script that appends a line to the beginning of files in a directory. The following code below does that.

```
 find . -type d \(  -name ThirdParty  -o  -name 3rdParty -o \
                    -name 3rd_party \) \
        -prune -o -type f \( -name "*.java"  -o -name "*.cs"    -o \
                             -name "*.cpp"   -o -name "*.cxx"   -o \
                             -name "*.cc"    -o -name "*.c"     -o \
                             -name "*.h"     -o -name "*.scala" -o \
                             -name "*.css"   -o -name "*.js" \) \
      -print0 | 
xargs -0 sed -i  '1s/^/\/*RIGHTS AND ETC ETC ETC/*'
```

However, I want to add this line ONLY if it is not already in the file. I have tried using `grep` and piping prior to using `sed` as such:

`grep -q "/*RIGHTS AND ETC ETC ETC/*" | sed -i....`

but, when I run the script I get `sed: no input files`. I am simply running this script in a directory so there are no input files. Thank you.

Comment: Please specify the operating system this code was tested on.  (*i.e.* Linux, BSD, OSX (Mac), *etc.*)

Answer (score 2):

`grep` isn't needed.  `sed` can do a negative search, and make the `i`*nsert* conditional:

```
... -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '1{/^\/\*RIGHTS AND ETC ETC ETC\*\/$/!i\
/\*RIGHTS AND ETC ETC ETC\*/
}'
```

---

Notes:

- the linefeeds in the three lines of code are necessary for `i` to work correctly.
- it's unclear whether the `*`s are literal or not, so they've been quoted like so `\*`.

Comment: the `*` are literals, does that make a difference in the above code? i ran it and it returned `sed: -e expression #1, char 8: unknown command: `*' ` for every time there was a `*`

Comment: @user10059339, What happens on your system if you run `sed '1{/^\/\*RIGHTS AND ETC ETC ETC\*\/$/!i\
/\*RIGHTS AND ETC ETC ETC\*/
}' <<< foo
` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `grep` command doesn't print anything, because you used the `-q` option; it just sets the exit status based on whether the file matched.

You want to print all the filenames that *don't* match, so you can pass those filenames to `sed`. You can do that with the `-L` option, along with `-z` to use a null terminator rather than newline (like the `-print0` option in `find`).

You should also use `-F` to treat the string as a fixed string, rather than a regular expression pattern.

```
find . -type d \( -name ThirdParty -o -name 3rdParty -o -name 3rd_party \) -prune \
    -o -type f \( -name "*.java" -o -name "*.cs" -o -name "*.cpp" -o -name "*.cxx" -o -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.c" -o -name "*.h" -o -name "*.scala" -o -name "*.css" -o -name "*.js" \) -print0 |
xargs -0 grep -Lz -F "/*RIGHTS AND ETC ETC ETC/*" |
xargs -0 sed -i ...
```

Comment: now it says `find: paths must precede expression:  -o` as well as the same sed error (no input files)

Comment: also the contents of each file are different, I'm not sure if you misunderstood the question or not. I just need to add that rights clause to the beginning of all the files inside the directory if it's not already there.  thank you so much!

Comment: If you split it over multiple lines as I did, make sure you don't have a space after the backslash.

Comment: I think I understand the question. `! -exec grep -q -F "string" {} \;` will match any files that don't contain that string.

Comment: I've added another method that's similar to what you were trying.

Comment: now it has the same errors as before plus `line 2: -o: command not found` and `line 3: -exec: command not found`

Comment: It still sounds like you have a space after the backslash on the first line.

Comment: Do you understand that the backslash is escaping the newline, to allow you to split the command over multiple lines?  So it has to be immediately before the newline, with no whitespace between them.

Comment: Ok i've removed the white space, but now its saying this `line 1: $'\r': command not found` for line 1 and 2. I am using cygwin, I should have included that but i realize now that it is relevant...

Comment: Now you have a Windows CRLF in your script. Fix it with `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and find):

```
(var="/*RIGHTS AND ETC ETC ETC/*" ;
find whatever  \! -exec grep -qF "$var" {} \; -exec sed -i '1i\'"$var" {} \;)
```

Where `whatever` are the initial find commands.

This will only insert the variable `var` if the grep did not find `var` anywhere in each entire file.

Comment: is there no semi colon needed after the first line for `var`? its timing out